# how do I call a public function in one controller from another controller cakephp 2.5

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

I have 2 separate controllers and I'd like to call a public function in controller1 from controller2, see code below, so in Name2Controller within searchApplicant() function I'd like to call searchProfile() function in Name1Controller.

```
<?php
class Name1Controller extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Name1';
    var $helpers = array('Paginator','Number');

    public function index() {
        $this->Applicant->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('applicants', $this->paginate());
    }

    public function searchProfile() {
    
    }

}


<?php
class Name2Controller extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Name2';
    var $helpers = array('Paginator','Number');

    public function index() {

    }

    public function searchApplicant() {
    
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't. If you want to have functionality which is shared between different controllers, put it into a class and use it that way (so that both controllers use the search functionality if they need do, by instantiating the class and calling its function). The controller only exposes functionality to the outside world (e.g. browsers or API clients), not to other parts of your PHP application.

Comment: _Side note:_ Defining class properties using `var` is a _very_ old legacy and should be avoided. It was used back in PHP 4, before the introduction of property visibility (public, protected, private).

Comment: you could move searchProfile() to AppCpntroller.php (I think you will need to load the Model used by searchProfile(), if it uses a model).

Then it will be available for any other controller...

Note...it is not a great idea...but it just will work